# Why is my Django view not automatically downloading a file

Tags: javascript, python, html, django, file

My view transcribes a file and outputs the SRT transcript. Then it locates and is supposed to auto download theT transcript but nothing happens after transcription completes(the file was submitted on a previous page that uses the transcribeSubmit view. The view that handles and returns the file is the initiate_transcription view). Here is my views.py:

```
@csrf_protect
def transcribeSubmit(request):
    
    if request.method == 'POST':
        
        
        form = UploadFileForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            

            uploaded_file = request.FILES['file']
            fs = FileSystemStorage()
            filename = fs.save(uploaded_file.name, uploaded_file)
            request.session['uploaded_file_name'] = filename
            request.session['uploaded_file_path'] = fs.path(filename)
            
            
            #transcribe_file(uploaded_file)
            #return redirect(reverse('proofreadFile'))
            return render(request, 'transcribe/transcribe-complete.html', {"form": form})
        else:
            
    else:
        form = UploadFileForm()

        
        
    return render(request, 'transcribe/transcribe.html', {"form": form})

@csrf_protect
def initiate_transcription(request):
    
    if request.method == 'POST':
        
        
        # get the file's name and path from the session
        file_name = request.session.get('uploaded_file_name')
        file_path = request.session.get('uploaded_file_path')
        if file_name and file_path:
            with open(file_path, 'rb') as f:
                path_string = f.name
                transcribe_file(path_string)
            
            file_extension = ('.' + (str(file_name).split('.')[-1]))
            transcript_name = file_name.replace(file_extension, '.srt')
            
            transcript_path = file_path.replace((str(file_path).split('\\')[-1]), transcript_name)
                
            file_location = transcript_path
            with open(file_location, 'r') as f:
                file_data = f.read()

            response = HttpResponse(file_data, content_type='text/plain')
            response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="' + transcript_name + '"'
            return response
            
        else:
            #complete

    return render(request, 'transcribe/transcribe-complete.html', {"form": form})

           
def transcribe_file(path):
#transcription logic
```

JS:

```
const form = document.querySelector('form');
form.addEventListener('submit', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    const formData = new FormData(form);
    const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

    xhr.open('POST', form.getAttribute('action'), true);
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
        console.log("ready state: ", xhr.readyState);
        console.log("status: ", xhr.status);
    }
    xhr.responseType = 'blob';
    xhr.send(formData);
});
```

HTML:

```
<form id="initiate-transcription-form" method="post" action="{% url 'initiate_transcription' %}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                    {% csrf_token %}
                <div>
                    <label for="output-lang--select-summary"></label>
                    <select class="output-lang-select" id="output-lang--select-summary" name="audio_language">
                        <option value="detect">Detect language</option>
                        <option value="zh">Chinese</option>
                        <option value="en">English</option>
                        <option value="es">Spanish</option>
                        <option value="de">German</option>
                        <option value="jp">Japanese</option>
                        <option value="ko">Korean</option>
                        <option value="ru">Russian</option>
                        <option value="pt">Portugese</option>
                <!-- add more language options as needed -->
                    </select>
                </div> 
                <button id="transcribe-button" type="submit">Click to Transcribe
                        <svg class="download-transcript" width="18" height="18" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
                            <path d="M19,9h-4V3H9v6H5l7,7L19,9z M5,18v2h14v-2H5z" fill="white"/>
                        </svg>
                            
                    </button>   
                
    </form>
```

The only response I get is the status: 200 console log in JS.

Comment: Check if file_path and file_name are both having value in the session

Comment: @MohamedElKalioby Hi. They both have valid values.